# Response method which is provided by the page class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, response

I need to create a button that will be offered to generate a printable invoice. This will reformat the webpage specifically for printing the buying tickets information.

I am only allowed to use one webpage, and somehow everything else on the page must disappear so that only the Printable Invoice shows. How can I do this?

I was told that "The trick is to use the Response method, which is provided by the Page class (more precisely, it is provided by a parent class named System.Web). 
What you show on the screen is managed by the System.Web object and using the Response method you can put anything you want in there. "

Answer (score 2):

No need to mess around with the `Response` object.

The trick is to use [CSS media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) - in particular a [print CSS file](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html).

Add a print CSS file to the page:

```
 <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="print" HREF="foo.css" />
```

In this file, you set the `display` property of everything you need to hide to `none` and you can tweak the CSS of what you need to display to optimize it for printing.

When users print, using the normal browser printing capabilities, this is what will be used to render the print.

Answer (score 1):

What the 'trick' means is that you can send whatever response you want. If for instance you want to send a pdf, you can change the Response to send the bytestream of the pdf, change the header and the client will be served a pdf file.

That said the question is very vague and has lots of possible answers. "Only allowed to use one webpage" - does this mean that you can only have one url, or one aspx file? Because you could very easily Server.Transfer to the second page, and that will give the appearance you're still on the same page.

Does it also have to be a webpage which contains this invoice? Or can you generate it with a tool (such as SQL Reporting Services) and serve it as a pdf?

The easiest way if you're stuck with a single webpage would be having two panels. One of which contains the 'invoice' the other contains what the page usually contains. If the user wants the invoice, hide the other panel and show the invoice. The invoice itself could/should be a custom control (ascx) so you can plug it in whenever you want and still keep a seperation of concerns.

Comment: Looks like we wrote our answers at the same time. My one demonstrates the method described in  Haedrian's final paragraph.